# ion auth registration view missing?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am in the process of installing ion auth into codeigniter and cannot find the the code in the auth.php controller for handling user registration. Nor can I find the registration form view file.

There is code for create_user(), which users with admin privileges can use, but I need to allow users to register themselves.

Does this code exist? If so where?

Answer (score 0):

The controller and views are just examples.  So add what you need.